# Times New Roman font installation problem in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts

I have installed times new roman font through terminal ubuntu 16.04, at the last moment terminal got struck. Now I cant reinstall times new roman font. I ran few commands with following result:

```
$ sudo apt update
  .
  . update done
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```